# How can I restart a specific Pod of a StatefulSet using client-go?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

My approach is:

```golang
func restartPod(meta metav1.ObjectMeta, kubeClient kubernetes.Interface) error {
    err := kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(meta.Namespace).Delete(meta.Name, deleteInForeground())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    return wait.PollImmediate(5*time.Second, 5*time.Minute, func() (done bool, err error) {
        pod, err := kubeClient.CoreV1().Pods(meta.Namespace).Get(meta.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            return false, nil
        }

        return pod.Status.Phase == v1.PodRunning && pod.Status.ContainerStatuses[0].Ready, nil
    })
}
```

It doesn't work because the deletion of pod is non-blocking, means it doesn't wait for the pod to be deleted. So the `Get` pod method returns the pod with running state. If I use `sleep` for some seconds after pod deletion then it works fine. Is there any better way to do this without using `sleep`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the metadata of every object there is UUID in a field called `uid`. You can compare and wait until the pod is Ready *and* has a different UUID. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#uids for more details (though really that's about all there is to say).

Comment: But be prepared for the case when the Pod never gets Ready again...

Answer (score 0):

```
import corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"

// RestartPod deletes a pod marked by a given label
// it then waits for a given timeout for the pod to resume running state
func RestartPod(c *client.ClientSet, label string, timeout time.Duration) error {
    pod, err := GetPodByLabel(label)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    podUid := pod.UID
    err = c.Pods(pod.Namespace).Delete(context.Background(), pod.Name, metav1.DeleteOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return wait.PollImmediate(5*time.Second, timeout, func() (done bool, err error) {
        pod, err := GetPodByLabel(label)
        if pod.UID != podUid && err != nil {
            return false, nil
        }
        return pod.Status.Phase == corev1.PodRunning && pod.Status.ContainerStatuses[0].Ready, nil
    })
}
```